# change PATH in makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

my simple makefile

```
#export PATH=/xxx/bin:$$PATH

$(info $(PATH))

export ABC=123

t:
        echo $${PATH}

        echo $${ABC}
```

runs fine. until I uncommented the first line. 
following is output before and after
before:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
echo ${PATH}
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
echo ${ABC}
123
echo 123
123
```

after:

```
/xxx/bin:$PATH
echo ${PATH}
/xxx/bin:$PATH
echo ${ABC}
123
echo 123
make: echo: Command not found
make: *** [t.mk:13: t] Error 127
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `export PATH := /xxx/bin:$(PATH)`.

Comment: thank you so much. why
export PATH := /xxx/bin:$(PATH) work,

Comment: @richard When you execute shell commands from make, `$PATH` is replaced by the value of the env variable `PATH` by the shell. But when you `export` a variable, there's no shell involved, so nothing replaces `$PATH`. By using `$(PATH)`, you're treating `PATH` as a `make` variable. Because there's no such variable in the makefile, `make` looks up the env variable with the same name instead.